# What is the motivation behind symplectic/orthogonal content?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Here $\lambda'$ is the conjugate partition of $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots)$ and cells are in the Young diagram.

The **symplectic content** of cell $(i,j)$ of $\lambda$ is defined by
$$c_{sp}(i,j)=\begin{cases} \lambda_i+\lambda_j-i-j+2 \qquad \text{if $i>j$} \\
i+j-\lambda_i'-\lambda_j' \qquad \qquad \text{if $i\leq j$}.\end{cases}$$

The **orthogonal content** of cell $(i,j)$ of $\lambda$ is defined by
$$c_{O}(i,j)=\begin{cases} \lambda_i+\lambda_j-i-j \qquad \qquad \text{if $i\geq j$} \\
i+j-\lambda_i'-\lambda_j'-2 \qquad  \text{if $i< j$}.\end{cases}$$

Although I have used these in my analysis, I still wonder:

> **QUESTION.** What is the motivation behind these definition choices for the "contents"?

Comment: What are $\lambda$ and $\lambda_i$?

Comment: I assume $\lambda$ is a partition with parts $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \dots$, while the parts of the conjugate partition $\lambda'$ are $\lambda'_1 \geq \lambda'_2 \geq \dots$.

Comment: Presumably there is a Type B/C/D hook-content formula that uses these? Although I have not seen that, and it is not discussed in e.g. Sagan's survey: https://users.math.msu.edu/users/bsagan/Papers/Old/uyt.pdf.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A hook-content formula, using the contents $c_{sp}(i,j)$ and $c_O(i,j)$,  for the dimensions of the irreducible polynomial representations of the symplectic and orthogonal groups, goes back to Ron King. I believe the relevant paper is https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0008414X00053086, but I did not check for sure.

Answer (score 5):

As I guessed in a comment above, there is apparently a symplectic/orthogonal hook-content formula which uses these notions. See "Hook-content Formulae for Symplectic and Orthogonal Tableaux" by Campbell and Stokke https://doi.org/10.4153/CMB-2011-105-7.

Warning: they seem to have withdrawn the arXiv version of their paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.4155) for reasons that are not clear to me.

EDIT: Regarding priority, I see Campbell and Stokke cite El Samra and King for the formula for the evaluation of the symplectic/orthogonal characters at $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ (i.e., pure counting of tableaux); what they do that is new is the principal evaluation $(1,q,\ldots,q^{n-1})$ (i.e., $q$-counting). Perhaps the arXiv withdrawal is about what Per said: copyright.

Comment: Sam: I was aware of this. But, what is the motivation?

Comment: I don't understand. The formula itself (counting/$q$-counting a certain kind of tableau) is a very natural analog of the hook-content formula. If that's not a good enough motivation, then I'm not sure how you could see the usual definition of content $j-i$ as motivated...

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan A natural reason would be that the referees gave a lot of insightful comments, and the paper went through a big overhaul. But then, the journal might not allow this improved version to be put on arxiv, due to copyright claims.

Comment: @SamHopkins: I see your point. I, too, don't see $j-i$ as motivated either.